# Memory leaks in windows server 2012 R2 not in windows 10 for a same application

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, .net-4.8

I have a .net framework 4.8 web api application running happily in windows 10. but the same app is having the memory leaks(memory keeps going high, not releasing) in a windows server 2012 R2 machine.

Does the GC makes any difference base on OS? its a 32-bit application.

Comment: [Yes, server GC works differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc)

Comment: Worth considering whether this is actually a problem. Apps using a lot of memory is only really an issue when something else needs that memory, the GC could just be waiting until the memory is actually required to release it. Is your Web API app actually causing problems on the server? If not, I'd devise some kind of test to load the machine and see if there's a potential problem there.